# Change password in memcached

Tags: memcached

How do I change/reset the password in a [Membase (formerly known as NorthScale) memcached](http://www.membase.com/products-and-services/memcached) instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it:

```
curl -u Administrator:currentPassword -i -d port=8091 -d secureServer= -d username=Administrator -d password=newPassword http://localhost:8091/settings/web
```